What is Moses saying in Exodus 32:32?
Exodus 32:30-32 NASBS
30 …Moses said to the people, “You yourselves have committed a great sin; and now I am going up to the LORD, perhaps I can make atonement for your sin.” 31 Then Moses returned to the LORD, and said, “Alas, this people has committed a great sin, and they have made a god of gold for themselves. 32 But now, if You will, forgive their sin—and if not, please blot me out from Your book which You have written!”
Is Moses asking to be punished instead of the people OR along with the people?

Moses on a mountain is offering his life for the people. Which is a shadow of Christ offering His life for us.


"Is Moses asking to be punished instead of the people OR along with the people?"

The text is not clear about this, but the implication is that Moses would rather die (spiritually as well as physically) than to witness the death of his people, while he was spared. After all, it was he who - with God's help - convinced them to leave Egypt at follow him into Sinai.
Let's also consider another argument - beside the request that he himself be written out of the book of life - that Moses used to convince God to "change his mind" or "repent."

12 Why should the Egyptians say, ‘With evil intent he brought them
out, that he might kill them in the mountains and wipe them off the
face of the earth’? Turn from your burning wrath; change your mind
about punishing your people. 13 Remember your servants Abraham, Isaac,
and Israel, and how you swore to them by your own self, saying, ‘I
will make your descendants as numerous as the stars in the sky; and
all this land that I promised, I will give your descendants as their
perpetual heritage.’” 14 So the Lord changed his mind about the
punishment he had threatened to inflict on his people.

This is a remarkable passage. Did Moses literally remind God of something He had forgotten, arguing that it would be extremely bad PR to kill the Israelites? Or was he demonstrating that he (Moses) understood God's true heart, which did not truly want to kill His own people? I think the answer that Moses' showed himself to truly understand God's feelings, something only a few people - such as David and Jesus - ever achieved. In other words, by his determination to sacrifice himself for the people's sin, Moses united with God at an unprecedented depth. This moved God to "change his mind" (some translators say "repent"), or at least to appear to do so.
Conclusion: From this perspective - although the answer is not entirely clear from the text itself - I favor the idea that Moses offered himself as a substitute for those who had sinned against God. In other words, he offered to die in their place, not along with them.

Almost all commentators suggest something similar to the pulpit commentary:

And if not, blot me, I pray thee, out of thy book. Some interpret this as merely equivalent to, "Blot me out of the book of the living,"
and explain that phrase as meaning simply - "Take my life - kill me
instead of them" - but something more seems to be meant. "The book of
the living" - "the book of life" - the book of God's writing - is not
merely a register of those who happen to be alive at any given time.
It "contains the list of the righteous, and ensures to those whose
names are written therein, life before God, first in the earthly
kingdom of God, and then eternal life also" (Keil). Thus Moses
declared his willingness - nay, his wish - that God would visit on him
the guilt of his people, both in this world and the next, so that he
would thereupon forgive them. St. Paul has a similar burst of feeling
(Romans 9:1-3); but it does not involve a formal offer - it is simply
the expression of a willingness. Ordinary men are scarcely competent
to judge these sayings of great saints.

That is, Moses of offering to pay the eternal price, giving up his place in heaven, instead the sinful nation.
Now, it is well-known that no human is worthy to pay the eternal divine price for sin which is why Jesus was the only One worthy to do so.  This is taught in several places in scripture such as:

Acts 4:12 - Salvation exists in no one else, for there is no other
name under heaven given to men by which we must be saved.”

However, it also demonstrated the humility and selflessness of Moses.

This answer would be better without "Now, it is well-known …" and the accompanying scripture. The question is one of the far too few questions on this site that can and should be answered strictly from the perspective of the Hebrew scriptures, without incorporating a Christian message.

@RayButterworth - that is the message of Heb 1 and Rev 5
